# Why I have gpiochip792 in /sys/class/gpio but `gpiodetect` says me that I have gpiochip0

Tags: embedded-linux, gpio, openbmc

Why I have *gpiochip792* in */sys/class/gpio* but `gpiodetect` says me that I have *gpiochip0*? In */sys/class/gpio* I have only *gpiochip792* link.

Answer (score 1):

*/sys/class/gpio* folder is visible when **legacy** GPIO interface is enabled. While the */dev/gpiochip0* is for new character device interface that has to be used. `libgpiod` project supplies a few shell tools to get an information about GPIO chips and manipulate lines on them (to some extent). That said, the two in the question are different representation depending on the ABI user wants to use.